# Adding entire list elements to a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following problem with my Python script. I have a list that contains a bunch of lat long coordinates like so...

```
l = [('-12.3790,45.2880',), ('-11.4660,43.8350',), ('-10.2810,42.1890',),   ('-9.0860,40.7450',), ('-7.8840,39.4580',), ('-6.6660,38.3070',), ('-5.4330,37.2710',)]
```

and I want to write that list into a file so that the data looks like this in a text file:

```
l = [('-12.3790,45.2880'), ('-11.4660,43.8350'), ('-10.2810,42.1890'),   ('-9.0860,40.7450'), ('-7.8840,39.4580'), ('-6.6660,38.3070'), ('-5.4330,37.2710')]
```

Notice that I don't want the comma after the lat long within (). How can I do that?

When I do:

```
with open('file.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(l[:])
```

That doesn't work

Comment: You are writing *tuples*, each with one element. Why would you want to write your data into a file just like that anyway? Creating a copy here to write is pointless, by the way, the `f.write()` call will not modify the list so `f.write(l)` would do the same thing.

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to write `[('-12.3790', '45.2880'), ...]` instead? Each element a tuple of two *separate* values for the longitude and latitude?

Comment: I'd still not just write the list to the file; I'd use a format more easily parsed like JSON, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you actually want the output format in your question, this will do it:

```
"l = [" + ", ".join(["('" + t[0] + "')" for t in l]) + "]"
```

Comment: The `l = ` part can be dropped, judging from how the OP was writing the list before.

Comment: Glad to be of help =)